# Why does the prompt remain even if I quit my command?

Tags: echo-area, message

I'm trying to write a function that should allow me to conditionally choose how to replace a regexp. E.g. if I have the string "A. Z" I'd like to choose if replace it with "A@. Z" or "A.~Z".

I wrote this function:

```el
(defun fix-latex-after-full-stop-space ()
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((a (point-min-marker))
           (case-fold-search nil)
           (case-replace nil))

      (catch 'quit
        (goto-char a)
        (while (search-forward-regexp  "[A-Z]\\. [A-Z]" nil t)
          (let* ((MATCH (match-string 0))
                 (CHOICE
                  (read-char-choice "Choose @, ~, \"n\" or \"q\"" '(?@ ?~ ?n ?q)))) 
            
            (cond ((char-equal CHOICE ?@)
                   (setq MATCH (replace-regexp-in-string
                                "\\. "
                                "\\@. "
                                MATCH t t
                                )))
                  ((char-equal CHOICE ?~)
                   (setq MATCH (replace-regexp-in-string
                                "\\. "
                                ".~"
                                MATCH t t
                                )))
                  ((char-equal CHOICE ?n)
                   nil
                   )

                  ((char-equal CHOICE ?q)
                   (throw 'quit nil)
                   
                   ))
            (replace-match  MATCH t t))))
      )))
```

But it has a strange behaviour. If I type "q" to quit or when I replace the last match the prompt doesn't quit but keeps asking for a char.

Whats wrong in it?

You can test it on:

```
A. Z

A. Z

A. Z
```

**Edit.** It happens that if I add `(princ "something")` after the `while` loop the minibuffer quits like I expect:

```el
(defun fix-latex-full-stop-space ()
  "DOCSTRING"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((a (point-min-marker))
           (case-fold-search nil)
           (case-replace nil))
      
      (catch 'quit
        (goto-char a)
        (while (search-forward-regexp  "[A-Z]\\. [A-Z]" nil t)
          (let* ((MATCH (match-string 0))
                 (CHOICE
                  (read-char-choice "Choose @, ~, \"n\" or \"q\"" '(?@ ?~ ?n ?q) t)))
            
            (cond ((char-equal CHOICE ?@)
                   (setq MATCH (replace-regexp-in-string
                                "\\. "
                                "\\@. "
                                MATCH t t
                                )))
                  ((char-equal CHOICE ?~)
                   (setq MATCH (replace-regexp-in-string
                                "\\. "
                                ".~"
                                MATCH t t
                                )))
                  ((char-equal CHOICE ?n)
                   nil
                   )
                  
                  ((char-equal CHOICE ?q)
                   (throw 'quit nil)
                   
                   ))
            (replace-match  MATCH t t))))
      (princ "") ;; <-- STRING ADDED HERE
      )))
```

but why?

Comment: In-between `search-forward-regexp` and `replace-match`, there are calls to `replace-regexp-in-string` and other functions which modify the match data. The match data object is global, so its inspection should happen immediately after it is set. Try wrapping everything between `search-forward-regexp` and `replace-match` in `save-match-data` and see if that helps at all. See [`(info "(elisp) Match Data")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Match-Data.html) for more.

Comment: @Drew I think the indentation should be right now.

Comment: I changed your question title. You can change it back or to something else if you like, but I think you were mistaken about the quit not occurring and the underlying question is why the prompt remains (giving the impression that the command wasn't done.

Comment: @Drew. Your changes are welcome! (My english is not much better than my elisp.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

What's happening is that you are indeed exiting the function, but *nothing is clearing the echo area, so your prompt remains there*.

You can use `(message nil)` or `(message "Done")` to clear it.  You can put that at the end of your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I can go for the "cosmetics" stuff to make it looks like the `query-replace-regexp` loop.